# Finding volume of region bound by the curves $y=\sin^2x$, $y=\cos^2x$ and he $y$-axis about $x=2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the curves $y=\sin^2x$, $y=\cos^2x$ ($0≤x≤\frac\pi4)$ and the $y$-axis about $x=2$ using both the disk/washer and cylindrical shell methods.

I know how to use the above method if it is a revolution around the axes but how do we use it to find the volume around a line?

Comment: Change coordinates $x_{\text{new}}=x_{\text{old}}-2$, so $x=2$ will become the $y$-axis.

Comment: Does this mean that I will integrate $cos^2(x-2) - sin^2(x-2)$ or $((cos^2x - sin^2x) -2)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{\pi/4}cos^2(x)dx - \int_0^{\pi/4}sin^2(x)dx$ is the region of the function on the x-y plane. Now integrate this area by rotating it around the line x = 2. 
This is the area of a disk, similarly you can determine the area of a washer. The key to this question is visualising the function in 2-dimensional space.

I hope this helps.